# How do I locate an object definition that does not show under Create - Objects

Tags: custom, object

I have an object in my system that a Trigger and class is using. I need to add a field to that object but I cannot locate where it is defined. I am an admin and can apparently see all objects in my system except this one. When I look under setup - Create - Objects I do not see it in the list. I can pull it up in developer console but cannot add a field to it through the developer console. I have look at the class being used by the Trigger and it does not contain anything to help me locate the Object. I know it's api name. How can I use that to find the object definition to add fields to it?

Comment: Is that object a custom settings object, perhaps? Or a system object? As far as I know, the only way to hide an object is to make it a protected custom settings object, in which case it's only accessible in the context of a managed package; otherwise, it must be some magic Salesforce object. It would be helpful if you told us the name of the object, if possible.

Comment: If you would change your comment mkorman to an answer I will gladly mark it as an answer. As a comment if I can mark it as an answer I do not know or see how to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that object a custom settings object, perhaps? As far as I know, the only way to hide an object is to make it a **protected custom settings object**, in which case it's only accessible in the context of a managed package; otherwise, it must be some magic Salesforce object. It would be helpful if you told us the name of the object.

Answer (score 1):

There is an chrome extension named MetaSearcher, you can locate any salesforce metadata by search them, then quick open them. It will save you a lot of time. Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: Installed it and searched for a couple of known objects with no result found. It failed to locate custom objects and objects created under the custom settings area.

Comment: Did you try to search them with object api name?

Comment: yes I did use the api name